# A kafka record is acknowledged but no data returned to consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

There is a Kafka (version `2.2.0`) cluster of 3 nodes. One node becomes artificially unavailable (network disconnection). Then we have the following behaviour:

1. We send a record to a producer with the given topic-partition (to the specific partition, let's say #0).
2. We receive a record metadata from the producer what confirms that it has been acknowledged.
3. Immediately after that we poll a consumer assigned to the same topic-partition and an offset taken from the record's metadata. The poll timeout was set to 30 seconds. No data is returned (an empty set is returned).

This happens inconsistently from time to time (under described circumstances with one Kafka node failure).

Essentially my question is: should data be immediately available for consumers ones it is acknowledged? What the reasonable timeout for that if not?

**UPD:** some configuration details:

- number of partitions for the topic: 1
- default replication factor: 3
- sync replication factor: 2
- acks for producer: all

Comment: Depends. Could you share you configuration? Specifically: number of partitions for the topic (are you sending to a specific partition?), replication factor, the 'acks' setting on your producer, 'isolation.level', or anything that is not default. And the kafka version.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I've updated my question with the requested details. I haven't mention acks and isolation level as they are default and aren't changed.

Answer (score 1):

The default setting of `acks` on the producer is `1`. This means the producer waits for the acknowledgement from the leader replica only. If the leader dies right after acknowledging, the message won't be delivered.

Should data be immediately available for consumers? Yes, in general there should be very little lag per default, should be effectively on the milliseconds range per default and without load.

If you want to make sure that a message can't be lost, you have to configure the producer to "acks=all" in addition to min.insync.replicas=2. This will make sure all in sync replicas acknowledge the message, and that minimum 2 nodes do. So you are still allowed to lose one node and be fine. Lose 2 nodes and you won't be able to send, but even then messages won't be lost.

Comment: I've just checked and actually we have ```acks``` for producer set to ```all```. I am sorry that I've not noticed that initially.

Comment: (Just to mention, your answer is still very valuable for me, so I've +1ed it)

Comment: Ok, there might be other issues, it's hard to debug through comments :) For example: are you under load, or you just sending one message which sometimes doesn't get delivered? Are you specifying partitions, or letting it auto-assign? Are there multiple consumers, and if yes, do they have the same id? Does the message actually arrive on the topic, or doesn't even get that far? (Un?)fortunately there are a hundred ways Kafka can be used/configured.

Comment: 1) No load, just sending one message. The message, I believe, is delivered, because we receive a RecordMetadata with a new offset. 2) The partition is specified explicitly. 3) There are multiple consumers, but they are on different instances; all with different unique group ids. 4) I believe that message arrives, because, as I mentioned earlier, we receive a new offset in the ack. information.

Comment: P.S. This problem is not consistent. Furthermore, the time when message becomes available for the consumer differs significantly: in the most cases it is within 2 seconds, but there are delays of 20, 30 seconds and so on. But apparently increasing the poll delay is not a solution.

Comment: P.P.S. That is to say, that messages are not lost. I think if I put an enormous poll delay, I don't know, may be 10 minutes, I will receive these messages in any case.

Comment: @Andremoniy Having delays when a node fails is normal, that alone is not a problem. It takes timeouts to notice that a node is gone (worst case replica.lag.time.max.ms is 10 seconds per default), and the consumer is only allowed to read a message when it is acknowledged by all ISRs. So either a node acknowledges or falls out of the ISR list eventually. I'm more worried about not receiving the message at all. Is the consumer assigned the partition at all? You could perhaps check the consumer log, or define a `ConsumerRebalanceListener` on `subscribe()` to explicitly log what's going on.